# pm 2 starts my bot, but the bot isn't online on discord

Tags: javascript, linux, discord.js, raspbian

I am hosting my discord.js bot on my raspberry pi 4. Everything works fine but obviously on a electrical outage I want my bot to start up again by itself.

What I tried:

```
pm2 start index.js --watch --ignore-watch="node_modules" --name MeguBot
pm2 startup
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u pi --hp /home/pi
pm2 save
```

now when I reboot my rpi it and do the `pm2 list` command I get this: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9pP7.png) (it shows my bot is started and running)

but the bot still stays offline on Discord

EDIT:

This is what I am getting in the error logs:

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN discordapp.com discordapp.com:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
```

Comment: Are you sure the bot can connect from your pi when not run through PM2 (e.g. `node index.js`)?

Comment: I just tried and it also works outside of pm2 by just executing the `node index.js` command

Comment: Have you checked PM2's logs for any errors that occurred?

Comment: From my understanding this is basically just trying to reconnect after a connection failure and is unable to, right?

Comment: You accidentally exposed your token in the linked upload, revoke it ASAP. Is the bot able to connect at all from your PI using PM2?

Comment: thanks for making me aware of it! 
Yes it is able to connect with PM2

Comment: Then my guess would be that the bot is unable to resolve the DNS of `discordapp.com` immediately after boot.

Comment: alright, do you have any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: I know that `pm2 restart 0` gets it going again, is there a way of executing that command a few seconds after boot

Answer (score 0):

PM2 is good but Forever or Nodemon are better. Check them out here https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: Forever is a good alternative to PM2, I disagree that Nodemon should be used in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks I will try them,
which of those would you recommend me?

Comment: Forever for production, nodemon for development

Comment: Okay so I tried using forever and I want to the js file of the bot executed on startup of the rpi. In `sudo crontab -e` I added `@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /home/pi/.dcjsbots/megubot/index.js` but it won't startup..,

Comment: Consult your system logs for more info on the failure.